# How do I save a file from logback fileappnder on AWS Function?

Tags: javascript, java, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, pulumi

I want to save the file from  logback file appender in /tmp directory in AWS Lamda function.
The logback config file look like this:

```
<configuration>
  <appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
    <file>tmp/app.log</file>
    <encoder class="net.logstash.logback.encoder.LogstashEncoder" />
  </appender>

  <root level="INFO">
    <appender-ref ref="FILE"/>
  </root>
</configuration>
```

My Pulumi code for AWS Lamda function look like this:

```
export const lamda = new aws.lambda.Function("aws-lamda-function", {
    code: new pulumi.asset.FileArchive("../app/build/libs/HelloWorldServerless-all.jar"),   
    runtime: aws.lambda.Runtime.Java11,
    handler: "HelloWorldServerless.HelloWorld::handler",
    role: lamdaExecutionRole.arn,
    name: "hello-world",
    memorySize: 300,
    timeout: 100,
    layers: [ 'arn:aws:lambda:eu-north-1:464622532012:layer:dd-trace-java:8',
              "arn:aws:lambda:eu-north-1:464622532012:layer:Datadog-Extension:38"],    
    environment: {
        variables: {
            DD_API_KEY:"*****",
            DD_CAPTURE_LAMBDA_PAYLOAD: "false",
            DD_LAMBDA_HANDLER: "HelloWorldServerless.HelloWorld::handler",
            DD_LOG_LEVEL: "debug",
            FUNCTION_NAME: "hello-world",
            DD_SERVICE: 'hello-world',
            DD_SITE: "datadoghq.eu",
            DD_VERSION: "0.1",
            DD_LOGS_INJECTION: 'true',
            DD_JMXFETCH_ENABLED: 'false',
            DD_TRACE_ENABLED: 'true',
            DD_ENV: 'dev',
            DD_MERGE_XRAY_TRACES: "false",
            DD_FLUSH_TO_LOG: "true"
        },
    },
},



)
```

The lamda role looks like this:

```
import * as aws from "@pulumi/aws";
import   {lamdaPolicy} from "./Policy"
import   {fileSystemPolicy} from "./Policy"
import   {vpcPolicy} from "./Policy"


export const lamdaExecutionRole = new aws.iam.Role("lamda-execution-role", {assumeRolePolicy: `{
 
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "lambda.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Effect": "Allow"
    }
  ]
}`,
 name:'lamda-execution-role',
 managedPolicyArns: [ 
     lamdaPolicy.arn,
     fileSystemPolicy.arn,
     vpcPolicy.arn,
     
     
 ]
}

);
```

With following policis:

```
import * as pulumi from "@pulumi/pulumi";
import * as aws from "@pulumi/aws";

export const lamdaPolicy = pulumi.output(aws.iam.getPolicy({
    name: "AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole",
}))

export const s3Policy = pulumi.output(aws.iam.getPolicy({
    name: "AmazonS3FullAccess",
}))

export const fileSystemPolicy = pulumi.output(aws.iam.getPolicy({
    name: "AmazonElasticFileSystemClientFullAccess",
}))

export const vpcPolicy = pulumi.output(aws.iam.getPolicy({
    name: "AWSLambdaVPCAccessExecutionRole",
}))


export const clodWatchPolicy = pulumi.output(aws.iam.getPolicy({
    name: "CloudWatchLogsFullAccess",
}))
```

The Javacode for logging looks like this:

```
package HelloWorldServerless;


import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.events.APIGatewayV2ProxyRequestEvent;
import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.events.APIGatewayV2ProxyResponseEvent;
import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.Context;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

import org.json.JSONObject;


public class HelloWorld  {  
    
     private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(HelloWorld.class);
        
    public APIGatewayV2ProxyResponseEvent handler(APIGatewayV2ProxyRequestEvent request, Context context)
    {   
        logger.info("Start handler");
        String requestMessage = request.getBody();
        JSONObject jsonMessage = new JSONObject(requestMessage);
        String messageValue = jsonMessage.getString("message");
        String responsMessageValue = messageValue.toUpperCase();
        String responsMessageKey = "{\"message\":";
        String responsMessage = responsMessageKey + "\"" + responsMessageValue.toUpperCase() + "\"" + "}";
        APIGatewayV2ProxyResponseEvent respons = new APIGatewayV2ProxyResponseEvent();
        respons.setBody(responsMessage);
        respons.setStatusCode(200);
        logger.info("End handler");
        return respons;
        
    }

}
```

When I run the Java code on the ASW function I get following error messages

23:33:47,950 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender[FILE] - File property is set to [tmp/logs/app.log]

23:33:47,954 |-ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender[FILE] - Failed to create parent directories for [/var/task/tmp/logs/app.log]

How do I manage to use the tmp directory to store the tmp/logs/app.log ?

Comment: To answer your question: `tmp` is not the same as `/tmp`

Comment: But, this is just an incredibly bad idea. Lambda execution environments come and go, you have no ability to control that, and unless you want to write a Lambda extension, you have no ability to capture the log files before the environment is destroyed. It's far better to use the default logging to CloudWatch and then, if you want to preserve somewhere else, save the CloudWatch logs.

Comment: Also, what does this question have to do with JavaScript?

Comment: It's always a bad idea to post API keys; please remove them

Answer (score 0):

As written in the comments, lambda environments come and go and you don't have write access to directories, as you found out.

Your question burns down to where you can write when you have a lambda function:

- The /tmp directory has 500MB disk space that can be used. Note that this directory will be cleared when AWS stops the function
- You can mount EFS persistent storage for storing files via the filesystem

In the end you can also save files in S3, but with an HTTP API.